# Desafio JSON e JS separar itens

Tags: javascript

Tenho seguinte código, que verifica quando um número foi pulado

```js
const dados = [
  { "cnpj": "1234567891011", "serie": "1", "numero": "1" },
  { "cnpj": "1234567891011", "serie": "1", "numero": "2" },
  { "cnpj": "1234567891011", "serie": "1", "numero": "3" },
  { "cnpj": "1234567891011", "serie": "1", "numero": "4" },
  { "cnpj": "1234567891011", "serie": "1", "numero": "5" },
  { "cnpj": "1234567891011", "serie": "1", "numero": "6" },
  { "cnpj": "1234567891011", "serie": "1", "numero": "7" },
  { "cnpj": "1234567891011", "serie": "1", "numero": "9" },
  { "cnpj": "1234567891011", "serie": "1", "numero": "10" },
  { "cnpj": "1213141516171", "serie": "1", "numero": "1" },
  { "cnpj": "1213141516171", "serie": "1", "numero": "2" },
  { "cnpj": "1213141516171", "serie": "1", "numero": "4" },
  { "cnpj": "1213141516171", "serie": "1", "numero": "5" },
  { "cnpj": "1213141516171", "serie": "1", "numero": "6" },
  { "cnpj": "1213141516171", "serie": "1", "numero": "7" },
  { "cnpj": "1213141516171", "serie": "1", "numero": "9" },
  { "cnpj": "1213141516171", "serie": "2", "numero": "10" },
  { "cnpj": "1213141516171", "serie": "2", "numero": "11" },
  { "cnpj": "1213141516171", "serie": "2", "numero": "12" },
  { "cnpj": "1213141516171", "serie": "2", "numero": "15" },
  { "cnpj": "1213141516171", "serie": "2", "numero": "16" },
  { "cnpj": "1213141516171", "serie": "2", "numero": "17" },
  { "cnpj": "1213141516171", "serie": "2", "numero": "21" },
  { "cnpj": "9090909871234", "serie": "1", "numero": "22" },
  { "cnpj": "9090909871234", "serie": "1", "numero": "1" },
  { "cnpj": "9090909871234", "serie": "1", "numero": "2" },
  { "cnpj": "9090909871234", "serie": "1", "numero": "3" },
  { "cnpj": "9090909871234", "serie": "1", "numero": "4" },
  { "cnpj": "9090909871234", "serie": "1", "numero": "6" },
  { "cnpj": "9090909871234", "serie": "1", "numero": "7" },
  { "cnpj": "9090909871234", "serie": "1", "numero": "8" },
  { "cnpj": "9090909871234", "serie": "3", "numero": "2" },
  { "cnpj": "9090909871234", "serie": "3", "numero": "1" },
  { "cnpj": "9090909871234", "serie": "3", "numero": "3" },
  { "cnpj": "9090909871234", "serie": "3", "numero": "4" },
  { "cnpj": "9090909871234", "serie": "3", "numero": "5" },
  { "cnpj": "9090909871234", "serie": "3", "numero": "6" },
  { "cnpj": "9090909871234", "serie": "3", "numero": "7" },
  { "cnpj": "9090909871234", "serie": "3", "numero": "8" },
  { "cnpj": "9090909871234", "serie": "3", "numero": "9" },
  { "cnpj": "9090909871234", "serie": "3", "numero": "10" }
];

const organizados = dados.reduce((acumulador, { cnpj, numero }) => {
  const copia = { ...acumulador };
  copia[cnpj] = [...(copia[cnpj] || []), parseInt(numero, 10)];
  return copia;
}, {});

const faltando = Object.keys(organizados).reduce((acumulador, cnpj) => {
  const numeros = organizados[cnpj];
  const [minimo, maximo] = [Math.min(...numeros), Math.max(...numeros)];
  const copia = { ...acumulador };
  copia[cnpj] = Array.from(Array(maximo-minimo), (v, indice) => indice + minimo).filter(item => !numeros.includes(item));
  return copia;
}, {});

console.log('CNPJs organizados: ', JSON.stringify(organizados));
console.log('Números faltando: ', JSON.stringify(faltando));
```

Gostaria que a saída fosse organizada, por exemplo:

**CNPJ:** 1234567891011
**Série 1:** 19
**Série 2:** 13, 18, 19, 20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você precisa só imprimir os valores... isso deve resolver

```
const imprime = (valores) => {
  for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(valores)) {
    console.log('CNPJ:', key);
    let serie1 = [], serie2 = [];
    for (let [k, v] of Object.entries(value)) {
      serie1.push(k);
      serie2.push(v);
    }
    console.log('Serie 1:', serie1.join(', '));
    console.log('serie 2:', serie2.join(', '));
  }
} 
imprime(organizados);
```

o exemplo completo você encontra [aqui](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-bpyjlm)

Comment: e se no caso tivesse mais uma série, a série 3?

Comment: provavelmente sua estrutura seria diferente.... ai teria que alterar o algoritmo, de acordo com sua estrutura é isso ai

Comment: Essa estrutura de *chave: valor* que você esta usando ela é tratada dessa forma ai... Se vc tivesse serie 1, serie 2, ... serie n, provavelmente teria que pensar numa estrutura recursiva com filhos, ou ate uma lista de listas, para ser completamente dinamico

Comment: No caso ela teria só mais a série 3 mesmo, seria 3 séries

Comment: Como seria feito, se preferir posso criar outra pergunta, pois estou quebrando cabeça aqui kkkkk

Comment: Respondendo sua outra pergunta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/370362/80265, o codigo completo pode ser encontrado aqui https://jsfiddle.net/x92was8q/5/

Comment: Lá ele não está verificando quando pulou, vou integrar os dois códigos

Comment: Verifique ai, creio que essa solução resolve ambos os casos.

Comment: sim, se conseguir juntar as duas soluções estaria perfeito